# Which way is better to reset index in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

There are 3 ways to reset `DataFrame` index:

- `reset_index()`,
- `reset_index(inplace=True)`,
- Manually setting the index via: `df.index = list(range(len(df)))`

Since inplace is going to be deprecated in pandas v2.0, which way is better, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When assigning to the index, the rest of the data in your DataFrame is not changed, just the index.

If you call `reset_index`, it creates a copy of your original DataFrame, modifies its index, and returns that. You may prefer this if you're chaining method calls (`df.reset_index().method2().method3()` as opposed to `df.index = ...; df.method2().method3()`), but for larger DataFrames, this becomes inefficient, memory wise.

Direct assignment is preferred in terms of performance, but what you should prefer depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.reset_index(inplace=True) -> returns None
```

Below solutions are faster:

```
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))

df.index = range(len(df.index))
```